# How to not export S4 class in roxygen2?

Tags: r, roxygen2

roxygen2 will generate Rd file if there are any documents for `setMethod` and `setGeneric`, but will not generate if I remove all comments.

Some example codes

```
#' @docType methods
#' @rdname fun-methods
setGeneric("fun", function(...){
    standardGeneric("fun")
})

#' @rdname fun-methods
#' @aliases fun,ANY,ANY-method
setMethod("fun", "ANY", function(x, y, ...){
})
```

In my R package, I would like to keep all comments, but not export or generate Rd file using roxygen2. How should I do it?

Comment: So you want to specifically use the `#' @rdname` comments which are the designed just for roxygen to make documentation, but you don't want to generate the documentation?  I'm not sure I understand. If you change the comments so they don't use the special roxygen syntax, you'll be fine.

Comment: Yes I realized I can change the comment style.  In my memory, roxygen2 will not generate Rd file if export is not specified.